# Prove that $hxyz$ is a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gcd-and-lcm

From The British Mathematical Olympiad, Paper 2, 1998, Question 3:

Suppose $x, y, z$ are positive integers satisfying the equation
$\frac{1}x - \frac{1}y = \frac1{z}$
and let $h$ be the highest common factor of $x, y, z$.

Prove that $hxyz$ is a perfect square.

Prove also that $h(y−x)$ is a perfect square.

Here is my attempt for part 1:

$\frac{1}x - \frac{1}y = \frac1{z}$

$yz-xz = xy\\z(y-x) = xy$

$x = c_1h\\y= c_2h\\z = c_3h$

$c_3h(c_2h-c_1h) = xy\\c_3h^2(c_2-c_1) = xy\\h^2(c_3(c_2-c_1)) = xy\\zh^3(c_3(c_2-c_1)) = hxyz\\h^4(c_3^2(c_2-c_1)) = hxyz$

And for part 2:

$h(y−x)=h^2(c_2-c_1)$

I need some hints on how to prove $c_2-c_1$ is a perfect square which I believe is the only step left; if any of my logic or presentation is wrong, please tell me as well.

Comment: You have $c_2-c_1$ divides $c_1c_2$ and $c_1,c_2$ are coprime. Suppose a prime $p$ divides $c_2-c_1$. Then it divides $c_1c_2$ and hence either $c_1$ or $c_2$. But it also divides their difference, so it must divide both. Contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why $c_2-c_1$ divides $c_1c_2$ or how the contradiction means that $c_2-c_1$ is a perfect square